# Need single click event in multiple playlists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I am using fancy music player in my website and I have multiple playlists in the format below:

```
<div class="playlist">
   <a href="mysong.mp3" class="fmp-my-track add_link">add this song</a>
   <a href="mysong.mp3" class="fmp-my-track add_link">add this song</a>
   <a href="mysong.mp3" class="fmp-my-track add_link">add this song</a>
</div>
<div class="playlist">
   <a href="mysong.mp3" class="fmp-my-track add_link">add this song</a>
   <a href="mysong.mp3" class="fmp-my-track add_link">add this song</a>
   <a href="mysong.mp3" class="fmp-my-track add_link">add this song</a>
</div>
<div class="playlist">
   <a href="mysong.mp3" class="fmp-my-track add_link">add this song</a>
   <a href="mysong.mp3" class="fmp-my-track add_link">add this song</a>
   <a href="mysong.mp3" class="fmp-my-track add_link">add this song</a>
</div>
```

I want when user click first time on any link in one playlist then it clears the playlist and on next clicks it adds the songs in playlist. For example, when user clicks any link from first playlist it clears the playlist and adds the song in playlist and on next click within this playlist it will not clear the playlist. When user clicks on any link from other playlist same here first time it will clear the playlist and then it will add the songs. I am using the code below to achieve this but it does not work:

```
$(".playlist").each(function(){
    $(".add_link").one("click", function(){
        $.fancyMusicPlayer.clear();
});
    $(".add_link").click(function(){
        $.fancyMusicPlayer.addTrack(this.href, this.title, this.target,false);
});
});
```

Adding the song in playlist is working fine, but the functionality of clearing the playlist on first click is not working. Can anyone  help me?

Comment: I think you are going to need to clarify what you are trying to achieve exactly. You want the visitor to be able to click on any song to start the `playlist`, and then you want the playlist to play all the other songs in that playlist, right?

Comment: no playing is automatic, there is no issue with playing just i want when user click first time in one playlist it clears the previously added songs in playlist and starts a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to keep a reference of the current playlist to check whether a new click is from the same or another playlist. Since your current playlist elements don't have an id, I used their index in the example code below:

```
var inPlaylist = 0;
$(".add_link").click(function(){
    var playlistIndex = $(this).parent('.playlist').index();
    if(playlistIndex != inPlaylist){
        $.fancyMusicPlayer.clear();
        inPlaylist = playlistIndex;
    }
    $.fancyMusicPlayer.addTrack(this.href, this.title, this.target,false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a selector issue. You want to iterate over each playlist and assign behaviors to each add_link in each playlist. But what you're doing is assigning behaviors to EVERY add_link ON THE PAGE, not in each playlist. $('.add_link') grabs every item on the page with every single iteration.

You should be doing this instead:

```
$('.playlist').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.add_link').one(...);
  $(this).find('.add_link').click(...);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! but its not working for me. i used this $('.playlist').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.add_link').one("click",function(){alert("check")});

it is alerting on all links, but it should alert on first click within one playlist